# Unable to fetch data from notification using fcm in onMessageReceived method

Tags: android, push-notification

Unable to receive push notification when app is in foreground. Also push notification is received in background but unable to fetch the data when push received. It is automatically generated by FCM

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.e("inside","inside");

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        JSONObject object=new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
        Log.e("jsonobject",object.toString());
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().toString());

//            if (/* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */ true) {
//                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
//                scheduleJob();
//            } else {
//                // Handle message within 10 seconds
//                handleNow();
//
//            }

        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
    // [END receive_message]

    /**
     * Schedule a job using FirebaseJobDispatcher.
     */
    private void scheduleJob() {
        // [START dispatch_job]
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(this));
        Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setService(MyJobService.class)
                .setTag("my-job-tag")
                .build();
        dispatcher.schedule(myJob);
        // [END dispatch_job]
    }

    /**
     * Handle time allotted to BroadcastReceivers.
     */
    private void handleNow() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Short lived task is done.");
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I am also getting this

> W/ContextImpl: forgetServiceDispatcher failed for:
>                                                                       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:
>   com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzad$zza@30f53b70

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzad$zza@30f53b70
                                                                            at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1105)
                                                                            at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1872)
                                                                            at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:562)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzad.disconnect(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzad.zzabl(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzad.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzad$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzf$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw$zzd.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what is this `Log.e("jsonobject",object.toString());`...displaying ?

Comment: i am trying to print the payload getting from remoteMessage

Answer (score 0):

please check if the versions are the same if you are using other google service like this. look at file build.gradle(Module:app)

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'
```

Check if the manifest file are similar to this one:

```
     ...<activity android:name=".actMyLastActivityFromManifest"></activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```